# Why am I not getting logging from Spring Security?

Tags: spring, spring-security, logback

I am trying to test my @PreAuthorize tags that are placed on the methods in my Spring Controller. I am not getting any logging information as to the decisions being made by Spring on whether to allow or disallow a call. Currently I am being allowed into a method and I want to debug why I am being allowed even though I don't have the role.

I am using Spring Framework 3.2.3, Spring Security 3.1.4, Logback 1.0.13, Logback Spring 0.1.1.

Here is my logback file:

```
...
<appender name="MAIN" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
  <file>/logs/main_log.txt</file>
  <append>true</append>
  <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
     <level>TRACE</level>
  </filter>
  <encoder>
     <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} | %p | %c %M | %m%n</pattern>
  </encoder>
  <rollingPolicy>
     <fileNamePattern>/logs/main_log.txt.%d</fileNamePattern>
  </rollingPolicy>
</appender>

<logger name="org.springframework" level="TRACE"/>

<logger name="my.package" level="TRACE"/>

<root level="WARN">
   <appender-ref="MAIN"/>
</root>
```

I have the listener set up properly in my web.xml file. I know this because I am getting log messages from the package my.package as well as WARN messages from 3rd party software.

Any ideas as to how I can see the decisions being made by the @PreAuthorize annotation?

Answer (score 3):

Your configuration seeems fine, but Spring unfortunately uses commons logging. Follow the official documentation on how to use SLF4J (+ log4j or logback).

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html#overview-not-using-commons-logging

Just don't add commons-logging jar or if you use Maven exlude it like shown in the documentation. Then you need a bridge between commons-logging and SLF4J (jcl-over-slf4j.jar).

Cut out from my (working) configuration:

```
<logger name="org.springframework" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</logger>
```

pom.xml:

```
    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.13</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.13</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

In order to use Pre-PostAuthorize annotations, it's necessary to enable their use in spring configuration, as they are off by default.

This is how to enable these annotations when using the `global-method-security` XML element (see [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html) for further details):

```
<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>
```